# How to install Python module "color_gradient"

Tags: python, python-2.7, module

I am extending a web based bio-informatics tool that is written in HTML, Javascript and Python. While running the application, one of the scripts gives the error:

```
[Fri Feb 27 13:22:27.528636 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 1267] [client 127.0.0.1:45930] AH01215: Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: http://localhost/circular/index.html
[Fri Feb 27 13:22:27.528757 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 1267] [client 127.0.0.1:45930] AH01215:   File "/var/www/localhost/cgi-bin/circular_handler_beta_v2.py", line 10, in <module>, referer: http://localhost/circular/index.html
[Fri Feb 27 13:22:27.528787 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 1267] [client 127.0.0.1:45930] AH01215:     import color_gradient, referer: http://localhost/circular/index.html
[Fri Feb 27 13:22:27.528828 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 1267] [client 127.0.0.1:45930] AH01215: ImportError: No module named color_gradient, referer: http://localhost/circular/index.html
[Fri Feb 27 13:22:27.538274 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 1267] [client 127.0.0.1:45930] End of script output before headers: circular_handler_beta_v2.py, referer: http://localhost/circular/index.html
```

The problem is that a module, calls "color_gradient" cannot be imported. I tried to search on Google where to find and install this module but I didn't get a satisfactory and clear answer.

Does anybody knows where to find and install this module?

The complete script is to long for sharing but here is the function where to module is used:

```
def get_genes(nc_code,strand,color):
cursor1 = conn.cursor()
if (strand == "+" or strand == "-"):
    # print ("SELECT start,stop,strand,locus_tag,ncbi_gi,cog,synonym,product FROM gene WHERE nc_accession = " + '"' + nc_code + '"' + " AND strand = " + '"' + strand + '"' + ";")
    cursor1.execute("SELECT start,stop,strand,locus_tag,ncbi_gi,cog,synonym,product FROM gene WHERE nc_accession = " + '"' + nc_code + '"' + " AND strand = " + '"' + strand + '"' + ";")
else:
    # print("SELECT start,stop,strand,locus_tag,ncbi_gi,cog,synonym,product FROM gene WHERE nc_accession = " + '"' + nc_code + '"' + ";")
    cursor1.execute("SELECT start,stop,strand,locus_tag,ncbi_gi,cog,synonym,product FROM gene WHERE nc_accession = " + '"' + nc_code + '"' + ";")
data = cursor1.fetchall()
# print  data
context_genes = []
for row in data:
    start,stop,strand,locus_tag,gi_code,cog,synonym,product = row   
    # print row
    add_data = ""
    cog_categories = []
    gene_color = color
    if color == "cog":
            gene_color,cog_categories = get_cog_color(cog)
    if color == "scl":
        scl,gene_color = get_scl(nc_code,gi_code)
        if gene_color == None:
            #Like unknown, but lighter grey
            gene_color = "#a9a7aa"
        if color== "Custom":
            if str(gi_code) in imported_custom_colors.keys():
                gene_color = imported_custom_colors[str(gi_code)]
            else:
                gene_color = "white"
    if feature == "gc_p":
        gcp, gcp_color = get_gene_statistical_data(nc_code,gi_code,feature)
        add_data = gcp
        if color == "scale_red_green":
            gene_color = gcp_color
        if feature == "gc_skew":
                gc_skew, gc_skew_color = get_gene_statistical_data(nc_code,gi_code,feature)
                add_data = gc_skew
                if color == "scale_red_green":
                        gene_color = gc_skew_color
        if feature == "at_skew":
                at_skew, at_skew_color = get_gene_statistical_data(nc_code,gi_code,feature)
                add_data = at_skew
        if color == "scale_red_green":
                gene_color = at_skew_color
    if feature == "numeric_data":
        try:
            add_data = float(numeric_data_data[str(gi_code)][0])
            gene_color = numeric_data_data[str(gi_code)][1]
        except:
            add_data = 0
            gene_color = "white"
    context_genes.append([start,stop,strand,locus_tag,gi_code,gene_color,synonym,product,cog_categories,add_data])
# print context_genes # empty
return context_genes
```

What I understood is that the rules:

```
if str(gi_code) in imported_custom_colors.keys():
            gene_color = imported_custom_colors[str(gi_code)]
```

are using the module.

Comment: Can you share the code in which you are including this library.

Comment: Yes, I added the function where the module looks like to be required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question to the person that made the application, he developed the module by himself and I got the module yet.